# How to test keyboard suggestions in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to force iOS to suggest a specific value on the keyboard for a text field after setting its `textContentType` to `telephoneNumber`? I'm trying to reproduce a behavior from a user but I'm not able to get the suggestions in the same format as him.

Comment: Hello! I am not sure if that is possible but you can try copying and pasting values into the `UITextField` to try and simulate the entry of multiple characters at once...